# Golang AWS S3 batch object creation

Tags: go, aws-sdk-go

I'm trying to create a bunch of "folders" inside s3 bucket. Was trying to duplicate the same approach as 
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/s3/s3manager/batch_test.go#L742 but this thing expects a "Body" which is not really needed in my case. 
So far the following code does what I need but I feel like there is a better "batched" approach that can be implemented.

```
serv := s3.New(session.New(s3h.Config))

for _, i1 := range []string{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"} {
    for _, i2 := range []string{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"} {
        req := &s3.PutObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(S3_BUCKET),
            Key:    aws.String(i1 + i2 + "/"),
        }
        serv.PutObject(req)
    }
}
```

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to create “folders”? There seems to be no use for this without objects “inside” of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "folders" in S3. At simple high level, S3 is a big key/value store. The list operation supports finding subsets of keys that begin with a certain prefix and can stop at a known delimiter (e.g. `/`), allowing it to look like it has file system like semantics.

Simply putting an object to `/a/b/c/d` which look like it has created folders `a`, `b` & `c` but it has simply created one object with that key. The list operation used in the console is stopping at `/` as a delimiter so it offers a folder like view.

You can't put multiple S3 objects in a single operation. Each one has to be uploaded as an individual operation. Using Go, I'd recommend you could have a channel which you put all uploads required and have multiple concurrent workers processing these to improve performance. You'd need to do some tuning to find the optimal amount. I wouldn't be surprised if there isn't already a library for this as this would be quite a common S3 use case.

Comment: Appreciate the answer!